# White blank screen is displayed on the simulator when I run my Swift app on xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm just learning Swift, and whenever I test my app, only a white blank screen is displayed on the simulator, however, when I close Xcode, the app loads up on the simulator and it works fine, does anyone know what's the reason for this?

Thank you very much in advance!

screenshot before closing xcode:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sh7cB.png)

screenshot after closing xcode:
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RT0HZ.png)

the code I used:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var priceTxt:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SalesTaxTxt:UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLbl:UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func calculateTotalPrice(_ sender: Any) {
        let price = Double(priceTxt.text!)!
        let salesTax = Double(SalesTaxTxt.text!)!
        
        let totalSalesTax = price * salesTax
        let totalPrice = price + totalSalesTax
        totalPriceLbl.text = "$\(totalPrice)"
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Remove the breakpoint (blue arrow/tag) seen in the first screenshot (and any other breakpoint you don’t need)

Comment: As @JoakimDanielson pointed out you need to right click on the blue arrow in line 11 and hit 'Delete Breakpoint' or disable breakpoints for your current debugging session by toggling the breakpoint symbol next to the |> on the bottom of your first screenshot.